# Remove duplicate from nsmutablearray containing nsdictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I want to remove duplicates from nsmutablearray.

Array Structure :-

> ```
> (
>     {
>         "act_end_date" = "";
>         "act_entry_date" = "13/11/2014";
>         "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily;
>         "act_start_date" = "2014-11-13";
>         "row_id" = 0;
>         "act_id" = 2;
>     }
>     {
>         "act_end_date" = "";
>         "act_entry_date" = "13/11/2014";
>         "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily;
>         "act_start_date" = "2014-11-13";
>         "row_id" = 1;
>         "act_id" = 2;
>     }
>     {
>         "act_end_date" = "";
>         "act_entry_date" = "16/11/2014";
>         "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily1;
>         "act_start_date" = "2014-11-15";
>         "row_id" = 2;
>         "act_id" = 3;
>     }
> )
> ```

What I want is to check where array contain any dictionary which have same act_id.
If yes then remove 1st dictionary.
i.e the expected result for the above arrayis :-

```
(
        {
            "act_end_date" = "";
            "act_entry_date" = "13/11/2014";
            "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily;
            "act_start_date" = "2014-11-13";
            "row_id" = 1;
            "act_id" = 2;
        }
        {
            "act_end_date" = "";
            "act_entry_date" = "16/11/2014";
            "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily1;
            "act_start_date" = "2014-11-15";
            "row_id" = 2;
            "act_id" = 3;
        }
    )
```

Is their any way?
Is it possible by using NSPREDICATE?

I Tries to do it in below way :-

```
  NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSMutableDictionary* E1 in Event_Array)
    {

        BOOL hasDuplicate = [[filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"act_id == %@", [E1 objectForKey:@"act_id"]]] count] > 0;

        if (!hasDuplicate)
        {
            [filteredArray addObject:E1];
        }
    }
```

For it returns array :---

```
(
    {
        "act_end_date" = "";
        "act_entry_date" = "13/11/2014";
        "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily;
        "act_start_date" = "2014-11-13";
        "row_id" = 0;
        "act_id" = 2;
    }
)
```

What i want is

```
(
    {
        "act_end_date" = "";
        "act_entry_date" = "13/11/2014";
        "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily;
        "act_start_date" = "2014-11-13";
        "row_id" = 1;
        "act_id" = 2;
    }
)
```

Comment: This is why creating a custom model object is so valuable.  In that case you could override `isEqual` and put the objects into a set in order to remove the dupes.  Overuse of dictionaries means the code is way more complicated than necessary.

Comment: You want row_id = 1 means latest id in duplicates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want the latest object to be in the list.

**Solution 1:** (Simple)

Reverse your array

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = Event_Array.count-1; i>= 0; i--)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* E1 = [Event_Array objectAtIndex:i];
    BOOL hasDuplicate = [[filteredArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"act_id == %@", [E1 objectForKey:@"act_id"]]] count] > 0;

    if (!hasDuplicate)
    {
        [filteredArray addObject:E1];
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Use NSMutableDictionary instead of array.

> ```
> //Keys are act_id(s)
> "2" = {
>     "act_end_date" = "";
>     "act_entry_date" = "13/11/2014";
>     "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily;
>     "act_start_date" = "2014-11-13";
>     "row_id" = 1;
>     "act_id" = 2;
> };
> "3" = {
>     "act_end_date" = "";
>     "act_entry_date" = "16/11/2014";
>     "act_recurrrance_type" = Daily1;
>     "act_start_date" = "2014-11-15";
>     "row_id" = 2;
>     "act_id" = 3;
> }
> ```

Comment: it's possible without for loop?

Comment: I don't think. if even there is any built-in method, there must be an inner loop in that method. BTW, why not loop?

Comment: @Shoaib Hi, I tried with your first solution but it occurs error like this `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<_SwiftValue 0x618000441680> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _id.'`

Comment: @DavidJonker please make sure you are using a valid key name.

Answer (score 5):

```
    NSMutableSet *keysSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary *msg in germanMakes) {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", msg[@"act_id"]];
    if (![keysSet containsObject:key]) {
        [filteredArray addObject:msg];
        [keysSet addObject:key];
    }
    }
    NSLog(@"filteredResults %@ keyset%@",filteredArray , keysSet);
```

germanMakes is your initial array, keysSet contains unique act_id (e.g. 1,2,3,4..), filteredArray is your array filtered by act_id. Keep in mind this does not get sorted ascending, but that part will be easy.