# NSMutableArray of unique NSMutableDictionaries

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fetching values from the data base and I am using the following code to create an NSMutableArray that contains unique NSMutableDictionary elements

```
  NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
  NSMutableArray *coreArray = [NSMutableArray new];
  NSLog(@"count %ld",[results count]); //prints 5

    for (NSManagedObjectContext * info in results){
        complianceId = [info valueForKey:@"complianceId"];
        coreDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)complianceId] forKey:@"comp_id"];
        NSLog(@"inner core dict %@",coreDict); //prints unique elements
        [coreArray addObject:coreDict];
        NSLog(@"array %@",coreArray); //prints an array containing same dictionary elements
    }
```

The resulting `coreArray` consists of the same dictionary elements. Howe can I be able to sort this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904295/remove-duplicate-from-nsmutablearray-containing-nsdictionary

Comment: I have tried it previousy

Comment: then what the issue u faced

Comment: The array has same element... The last element

Comment: pardon........?

Comment: the array is filled entirely with the last element

Comment: what is `coreDict`? please post you _real_ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have one dictionary `coreDict` and you are adding this same dictionary to your array on every loop.
Whenever you set the value for the key `comp_id` it is changing that value in all instances of `coreDict`.

Instead you should create a new dictionary on every loop and add that to the array.

Replace:

```
[coreDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)complianceId] forKey:@"comp_id"];
[coreArray addObject:coreDict];
```

with:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"comp_id":[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)complianceId]};
[coreArray addObject:dict];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please add NSSortDescriptor and NSPredicate in your request!! That will help sort based on keys..

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate* predicate = nil; // Create your predicate here!!
    if (predicate)
    {
        [request setPredicate:predicate];
    }
    NSString *sortKey = @"complianceId";
    if (sortKey)
    {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortKey ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    }
    NSArray *results = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Answer (score -1):

Use on NSFetchRequest the following code. It will solve your problem.

fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = YES